# Uncaught Error: reCAPTCHA has already been rendered in this element

Tags: javascript, recaptcha

I am trying to place multiple Captcha in single vf page. this are written in visualforce component. while loading i am able to see only one Captcha. when i have done inspect elements i got this error:

[error Message pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxRdc.png)

**VF Component:**

```
<apex:component >
<apex:attribute type="CmpResult" name="recaptaReslt" required="true" description="Show or Hide the button" assignTo="{!reslt}"/>
<head>
    <apex:slds />
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var onloadCallback = function() {
        grecaptcha.render('theCAPTCHA', {
            'sitekey' : '6Lecb0AUAAAAADqGh7PRcKG1tmB2EChkJhObgdpF',
            'callback' : verifyCallback,
            'expired-callback' : expiredCall,
            'theme' : 'light'
        });
    };

    var verifyCallback = function(response) {
        if (response == ""){

        }
        else{
            validate(response);
        }
    }

    var expiredCall = function() {
        expireVerification();
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="slds-scope">
        <apex:form>
            <div id="theCAPTCHA" class="g-recaptcha" style="transform: scale(0.74);transform-origin: 0 0;-webkit-transform:scale(0.74);-webkit-transform-origin: 0 0"></div>
            <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit"></script>
            <apex:actionFunction name="validate" action="{!verifyResponse}" reRender="enableButton">     
                <apex:param name="firstParam" assignTo="{!tok}" value="" />
                    </apex:actionFunction>
                <apex:actionFunction name="expireVerification" action="{!expireToken}" reRender="disableButton"/>   

                    </apex:form>
                </div>
                </body>
                </apex:component>
```

Comment: You have rendered google captcha via java script so remove class "g-recaptcha" from your div where you want to display google recaptcha or do reverse.

Comment: i have removed. even it's not working.

Comment: Just do one thing make "g-recaptcha" as it is and remove "?onload=onloadCallback" from google captcha script you have included.