# reCAPTCHA has already been rendered in this element

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-apps-script, updatepanel, recaptcha

I have a simple contact form built with ASP .Net using the updatepanel. Everything works as expected but i see the error

**recaptcha__en.js: Uncaught Error: reCAPTCHA has already been rendered in this element**

in the console window

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=pageLoad&render=explicit" async defer></script>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="XXXX"></div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function pageLoad() {
        $('.g-recaptcha').each(function (index, obj) {
            grecaptcha.render(obj, { 'sitekey': 'XXXX' });
        });
    }
</script>
```

I initially added `onload=pageLoad&render=explicit` as if the captcha was not checked and you clicked the button to send, the captcha disappeared. Adding `onload=pageLoad&render=explicit` to the script line resolved this but now i get the above error.

If i try and remove some elements then something else breaks i.e. captcha doesnt display or is not displayed on postback?

Comment: Did you perhaps add `<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha` twice on the page? Check the html to be sure.

Comment: Just did a search on the page under view source and no, its only listed once.

Comment: Have you tried the suggestion in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52754893/uncaught-error-recaptcha-has-already-been-rendered-in-this-element)?

Comment: Yes i tried that but i get different issues ranging from this error Uncaught TypeError: grecaptcha.render is not a function to the captcha disappearing on postback.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem a couple days ago with a dynamic login and creation form. The reason was that I was rendering twice at the same element.

The Google ReCaptcha Throws an exception notifying said problem.

My solution was use `try{...}catch(event){...}` as wrapper for `grecaptcha.render()`

```
try{
    grecaptcha.render('elementID', {
        'sitekey' : 'key',
        'badge' : 'att',
        'size' : 'att',
        'tabindex' : 0,
        'callback' : function(token) {
            //..
        },
        'expired-callback' : function() {
            //...
        },
        'error-callback' : function() {
            //...
        },
        'isolated' : false
    });
}catch(error){/*possible duplicated instances*/}`
```

Comment: did not work for me, still fires the error

Answer (score 4):

For those who are using React with Firebase and in case this error occurs,
you just have to destroy the instance of Recaptcha on unmount of your component.

```
useEffect(() => {
const verifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier(element.current, {
  size: "invisible",
});
    if (!recaptcha) {
        verifier.verify().then(() => setRecaptcha(verifier));
    }
return () => {
  verifier.clear()
}
});
```

Comment: This makes sense. Could you provide the full page?
Im interested in where you're getting recaptcha and setRecaptcha

Comment: @itshinkswhenitscold, `const [recaptcha, setRecaptcha] = useState()`

Answer (score 1):

If  you use Angular with firebase, you must destroy the RecaptchaVerifier after use

```
//if for example you have declared it as such:
recaptchaVerifier: firebase.default.auth.RecaptchaVerifier;

//you can destroy it as such:
this.recaptchaVerifier.clear()

//you must do for example the destruction when you navigate to a new component
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!window.recaptchaVerifier) {
    window.recaptchaVerifier = new RecaptchaVerifier('sign-in-button', {
        'size': 'invisible',
        'callback': (response) => {
            console.log(response)
        },
        'expired-callback': () => {

        }

    }, auth);
}
```

fix it by adding if()

Answer (score 0):

For angular users, try the **google recaptcha v2** using the site key in a try and catch block.

Comment: the sitekey is string, how do you add it in try/catch? would you please provide a sample?