# Issue with Resending OTP using Firebase Authentication with Phone Number Sign-in

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am implementing a resend OTP functionality using Firebase Authentication with phone number sign-in in my web application. I am using the Firebase JavaScript SDK and have followed the documentation to set up the reCAPTCHA verifier. However, I am encountering issues related to reCAPTCHA rendering and resetting.

Specifically, I am getting an error  when trying to render the reCAPTCHA widget multiple times on the same element:

> reCAPTCHA has already been rendered in this element

I have tried to use the `reset()` method of the `RecaptchaVerifier` instance to reset the reCAPTCHA widget before rendering it again, but it is not working. I am also getting an error:

> recaptchaVerifier.reset is not a function

Additionally, I am encountering an `auth/internal-error` error when trying to resend the OTP using the `signInWithPhoneNumber()` function with the updated `RecaptchaVerifier` instance.

Can someone please help me identify and resolve the issue with resending OTP using Firebase Authentication with phone number sign-in?

```
 let recaptchaVerifier;

    function setUpRecaptha(number) {

        recaptchaVerifier = new RecaptchaVerifier(
            "recaptcha-container",
            { 'size': 'invisible' },
            auth
        );

        recaptchaVerifier.render().then((widgetId) => {
            window.recaptchaWidgetId = widgetId;
        });
        // recaptchaVerifier.render();

        return signInWithPhoneNumber(auth, number, recaptchaVerifier);
    }

     const getOtp = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(number);
        setError("");
        if (number === "" || number === undefined)
            return setError("Please enter a valid phone number!");
        try {
            const response = await setUpRecaptha(number);
            setResult(response);
            setFlag(true);
        } catch (err) {
            setError(err.message);
        }
    };

    function setUpRecapthaNew(number) {
        console.log("recaptchaVerifier", recaptchaVerifier)

        if (!recaptchaVerifier) {
            recaptchaVerifier = new RecaptchaVerifier(
                "recaptcha-container",
                { 'size': 'invisible' },
                auth
            );

            recaptchaVerifier.clear(); 

            recaptchaVerifier.render().then((widgetId) => {
                window.recaptchaWidgetId = widgetId;
            });
            // recaptchaVerifier.render();
        }
        console.log("widged it", window.recaptchaWidgetId)
        console.log("recaptchaVerifier", recaptchaVerifier)

        return signInWithPhoneNumber(auth, number, recaptchaVerifier);
    }

    const resendOtp = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(number);
        setError("");
        if (number === "" || number === undefined)
            return setError("Please enter a valid phone number!");
        try {

            const response = await setUpRecapthaNew(number);
            console.log("response", response)
            setResult(response);
            setFlag(true);
        } catch (err) {
            setError(err.message);
        }
    };
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [reCAPTCHA has already been rendered in this element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54110489/recaptcha-has-already-been-rendered-in-this-element)

Comment: Thanks for the response @MarkMunene, but it is still throwing the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a way to bypass this error

since  recaptchaVerifier.clear() is not working for me so I unmounted the element and then remounted it

```
 // Remove the DOM element that contains the reCAPTCHA widget
        const recaptchaContainer = document.getElementById("recaptcha- container");
        recaptchaContainer.parentNode.removeChild(recaptchaContainer);

        // Recreate the DOM element
        const newRecaptchaContainer = document.createElement("div");
        newRecaptchaContainer.id = "recaptcha-container";
        document.body.appendChild(newRecaptchaContainer);
```